# Is it possible to override default # products in a row in custom Shopify collections template?

Tags: collections, grid, shopify

I have created an alternate collection.liquid template for a shopify site I'm working on. My struggle is with not being able to control the number of products that appear in a row in the grid. I developed the custom template so that I wouldn't affect the number of products/row that appear on the other collections.

The code that displays the grid in my liquid template is this:

```
<div class="four columns section_select {% unless settings.collection_sort %}offset-by-four omega{% endunless %}">
{% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
        {% if forloop.first %}
<label for="tag_filter" class="inline">
{{ 'collections.sorting.filter' | t }}: </label> 
<select name="tag_filter" id="tag_filter">
<option {% unless current_tags %}selected="selected"{% endunless %} value="{% if collection.handle == "all" %}/collections/all{% else %}{{ collection.url }}{% endif %}">{{ 'collections.general.all_collection_title' | t: title: collection.title }}</option>
        {% endif %}
        {% unless tag contains 'meta-related-collection-' %}
          <option {% if current_tags contains tag %}selected="selected"{% endif %} value="/collections/{% if collection.handle != blank %}{{ collection.handle }}{% else %}all{% endif %}/{{ tag | handleize }}">{{ tag }}</option>
        {% endunless %}

        {% if forloop.last %}
          </select>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      </div>
```

Even when I change the class class="four columns" to something else, it is not reflected on my collection.

The problem could be in my code that assigns how many products are pulled in this collection but I can't seem to make a difference.

```
{% case products_per_row %}
  {% when '1' %}
    {% assign grid_item_width = 'medium--one-third large--one-whole' %}
  {% when '2' %}
    {% assign grid_item_width = 'medium-down--one-half large--one-half' %}
  {% when '3' %}
    {% assign grid_item_width = 'medium--one-third large--one-third' %}
  {% when '4' %}
    {% assign grid_item_width = 'medium-down--one-half large--one-quarter' %}
  {% when '5' %}
    {% assign grid_item_width = 'medium-down--one-half large--one-fifth' %}
{% endcase %}
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your theme is using Timber grid. 
You will find grid structure and classes to use in documentation here: https://shopify.github.io/Timber/

HTH